# How do I show the exact command being tested when a pytest script runs?

Tags: pytest

How is it possible that anyone uses pytest without having it output the exact command that it runs.

I have a set of 5 test scripts with a total of 41 different test combinations.  The script functions all basically follow this same template where at some stage, the funciton does:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmdline_builder(opt, name, options))
```

When there's a failure, the output is nearly useless,   it doesn't show the *exact* command that was run.

How does anybody use this ?  How would you expect to debug a failed test without knowing what to run ?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: You should catch exceptions of Popen and then do the assertions. It looks like you are getting failures deep in Popen which is not useful.

Comment: > How does anybody use this ? How would you expect to debug a failed test without knowing what to run ?

To answer that, almost nobody runs test that way. Standard way to run test is to use pytest directly in terminal. To run pytest programmatically, use pytest.main method. You are using archaic and non-standard way to run pytest and blaming it on tool.